# ayuda con funcion includes para buscar en un array js

Tags: javascript

tengo este array

```
detallesImei `0: {imei1: "aaaa", imeip: "1"} 1: {imei1: "aaaal", imeip: "1"}
```

quiero validar con js que cuando inserte otro dato no exista en `imei1`para ello quiero usar `includes()` que me devuelve true o false, como puedo hacer que funcione lo tengo de esta manera pero siempre sale false aunque exista en el array `detallesImei.includes(element1 => element1.imei1 "aaaa");`y deberia salir true

Answer (score 2):

El método `includes` espera por parámetro el objeto en concreto a comprobar que esté en el *array*. Es decir,

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(arr.includes(2)); // true
console.log(arr.includes(10)); // false
```

En tu caso, al tratarse de objetos, no mira por valor sino por referencia. Es decir,

```
const arr = [
  { imei1: 'aaaa', imeip: '1' },
  { imei1: 'aaaal', imeip: '1' }
];

const assert = arr.includes({ imei1: 'aaaa', imeip: '1' });
console.log(assert); // false
```

Porque el objeto que se pasa por argumento no es el mismo que el que está en el *array*, aunque tenga el mismo valor. Para aclarar eso...

```
const obj = { imei1: 'aaaa', imeip: '1' };

const arr = [
  obj,
  { imei1: 'aaaal', imeip: '1' }
];

const assert = arr.includes(obj);
console.log(assert); // true
```

Si lo que quieres comprobar es que **algún** elemento del *array* cumpla con una condición en concreto, debes usar el método `some`.

```
const arr = [
  { imei1: 'aaaa', imeip: '1' },
  { imei1: 'aaaal', imeip: '1' }
];

const assert = arr.some(e => e.imei1 === `aaaa`);
console.log(assert); // true
```

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 0):

```
const finded = detallesImei.every(item => item.imei == "aaa")
```

Devolverá true si alguno cumple la condición.
Devolverá false si ningún imei es "aaa".

**finded es un booleano.**